# Css remove default label text and keep the current

Tags: html, css

```
<label for="billing_city" class="">City <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
```

I have this label. I changed its text with this css:

```
label[for="billing_city"]:before{content:'Please select city: '}
```

But I need to hide the `"City"` string in the original content. Is there any css-trick to do that easy? My problem it doesn't have any class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some `font-size` trick like this:

```css
label[for="billing_city"] {
  font-size:0; /*Hide the whole content*/
}

label[for="billing_city"]:before {
  content: 'Please select city: ';
  font-size:initial; /* Make only this visible */
}
label[for="billing_city"] * {
  font-size:initial; /* Make also visible any other inner content */
}
```

```html
<label for="billing_city" class="">City <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use text-indent and overflow:

```
label[for="billing_city"]{
    text-indent:-200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

label[for="billing_city"]:before {
    content: 'Please select city: ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

It's an ugly fix, but it works. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us3x65fL/)

Any CSS-fix would be the "wrong thing" to do here - it would be much better and make more sense if you could change the label directly in the HTML.

Comment: why the left:200px .. i didn't test but it should not be left:0 ?

Comment: also if you use position absolute you will loose the normal flow and you may have some content overlap/overflow, so we need to pay attention to this

Comment: The text-indent for the label pushes everything 200px to the left - also the absolute-positioned :before, therefore the left:200px;. I totally agree with your concern about the use of position:absolute; as I say: it's an ugly fix, and it would be better to change in the HTML.

Comment: hmm, i test it but it's not working for me ... the city text stay in the initial place. I think it works only with block element and not inline element. And if we change it to block, we can broke the layout ..

Comment: at least you can make it inline-block and it will be fine ;)

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten the display:block; and it works now - though your solution is definitely better.